# Pandas timeseries groupby using TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series which is like this

```
            Time    Demand
Date        
2014-01-01  0:00    2899.0
2014-01-01  0:15    2869.0
2014-01-01  0:30    2827.0
2014-01-01  0:45    2787.0
2014-01-01  1:00    2724.0
2014-01-01  1:15    2687.0
2014-01-01  1:30    2596.0
2014-01-01  1:45    2543.0
2014-01-01  2:00    2483.0
```

Its is in 15 minute increments. I want the average for every hour of everyday.So i tried something like this `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='H')).mean()`. It didn't work out quite right because it returned mostly`NaNs`.

Now my dataset has data like this for the whole year and I would like to calculate the mean for all the hours of all the months such that I have 24 points but the mean is for all hours of the year e.g. the first hour get the mean of the first hour for all the months. The expected output would be

```
 2014 00:00:00  2884.0
 2014 01:00:00  2807.0
 2014 02:00:00  2705.5
 2014 03:00:00  2569.5
 ..........
 2014 23:00:00  2557.5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first add `Time` column to `index`:

```
df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df.Time + ':00')
print (df)
                     Time  Demand
2014-01-01 00:00:00  0:00  2899.0
2014-01-01 00:15:00  0:15  2869.0
2014-01-01 00:30:00  0:30  2827.0
2014-01-01 00:45:00  0:45  2787.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00  1:00  2724.0
2014-01-01 01:15:00  1:15  2687.0
2014-01-01 01:30:00  1:30  2596.0
2014-01-01 01:45:00  1:45  2543.0
2014-01-01 02:00:00  2:00  2483.0

print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).mean())
#same as
#print (df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='H')).mean())
                     Demand
2014-01-01 00:00:00  2845.5
2014-01-01 01:00:00  2637.5
2014-01-01 02:00:00  2483.0
```

Thanks [pansen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487762/pandas-timeseries-groupby-using-timegrouper/42487874?noredirect=1#comment72115818_42487874) for another idea `resample`:

```
print (df.resample("H").mean())
                     Demand
2014-01-01 00:00:00  2845.5
2014-01-01 01:00:00  2637.5
2014-01-01 02:00:00  2483.0
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
            Time  Demand
Date                    
2014-01-01  0:00     1.0
2014-01-01  0:15     2.0
2014-01-01  0:30     4.0
2014-01-01  0:45     5.0
2014-01-01  1:00     1.0
2014-01-01  1:15     0.0
2015-01-01  1:30     1.0
2015-01-01  1:45     2.0
2015-01-01  2:00     3.0

df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df.Time + ':00')
print (df)
                     Time  Demand
2014-01-01 00:00:00  0:00     1.0
2014-01-01 00:15:00  0:15     2.0
2014-01-01 00:30:00  0:30     4.0
2014-01-01 00:45:00  0:45     5.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00  1:00     1.0
2014-01-01 01:15:00  1:15     0.0
2015-01-01 01:30:00  1:30     1.0
2015-01-01 01:45:00  1:45     2.0
2015-01-01 02:00:00  2:00     3.0

df1 = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.hour]).mean().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['year','hour','Demand']
print (df1)
   year  hour  Demand
0  2014     0     3.0
1  2014     1     0.5
2  2015     1     1.5
3  2015     2     3.0
```

For `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
df1 = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.hour]).mean()
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) + 
                           df1.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str), format='%Y%H')
print (df1)
                     Demand
2014-01-01 00:00:00     3.0
2014-01-01 01:00:00     0.5
2015-01-01 01:00:00     1.5
2015-01-01 02:00:00     3.0
```

Comment: Nice solution with the modified `df.index` :-). For aggregation, you may also use `df.resample("H").mean()` without requiring the groupby which is a bit easier.

Comment: Nice solution. Now my dataset has data like this for the whole year and I would like to calculate the mean for all the hours of all the months such that I have 24 points but the mean is for all hours of the year e.g. the first hour get the means of the first hour for all the months. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some sample with desired output? Because I am not sure if I understand you. Thanks.

Comment: `2014 00:00:00  2845.5
  2014 01:00:00  2657.5
  2014 02:00:00  2423.0`

Comment: because formatting of comments is horrible. Thanks.